# The second derivative of the Dirac delta function

Tags: dirac-delta

I want to output the following expression: $tδ^{''}\left(t\right)=-2δ^{'}\left(t\right)$

My attempt, which did not lead to success: $\int_{ }^{ }δ^{'}\left(t-s\right)f^{''}\left(t\right)dt=f^{''}\left(s\right)$

$-\int_{ }^{ }δ^{''}\left(t-s\right)f^{'}\left(t\right)dt=f^{''}\left(s\right)$

$f^{'}\left(t\right)=g^{'}\left(t\right)\left(t-s\right)$

$-\int_{ }^{ }δ^{''}\left(t\right)\cdot t\cdot g^{'}\left(t+s\right)dt=g^{'}\left(s\right)$

$g^{'}\left(s\right)=\int_{ }^{ }g^{'}\left(t\right)δ\left(t-s\right)$

$δ^{''}\left(t\right)t=-δ\left(t\right)$

I probably made a mistake somewhere

Comment: What is the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t \delta''(t) f(t)dt$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(t) f(t)dt$

Comment: In your very first line, don't you mean to use the idea that $\delta$, not its derivative, is the "identity operator" under convolution? That's not a good start. In any case, I think you are doing more work than is necessary...

Answer (score 1):

This *should* be a standard sort of computation, I think simpler than what you wrote. Short of doing the induction that proves, analogously, that $t\delta^{(n)}=-n\cdot \delta^{(n-1)}$, the explicit computations for $n=1,2$ are adequate to suggest the full case. The notation may be slightly different than what is familiar to you, but I claim it is very economical, and accurate. :)

Namely, $$(t\delta')(f)\;=\;\delta'(tf)\;=\;-\delta({d\over dt}(tf))\;=\;-\delta(f+tf')\;=\;-\delta(f)+(0\cdot f'(0)=-\delta(f)$$
That is, $t\delta'=-\delta$. An example of the induction step is
$$
(t\delta'')(f) \;=\; \delta''(tf) \;=\; (\delta')'(tf)\;=\; -\delta'({d\over dt}(tf)) \;=\; -\delta'(f+tf') \;=\; -\delta'(f)-\delta'(tf')
$$ $$ \;=\; -\delta'(f)-(t\delta')(f')
\;=\; -\delta'(f)+\delta(f')
\;=\; -\delta'(f)-\delta'(f) \;=\; -2\cdot \delta'(f)
$$

Comment: +1 for the ["(Nice) Short and Accurate (Prophecies) Notation of Agnes Nutter, Witch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Omens) comment at the end of the first paragraph, made me smile. :)

Comment: @prets Ha! I must be channeling them... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with this identity of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))
   $$ t\delta(t)~=~0.$$
2. Differentiate
   $$ \delta(t)+t\delta^{\prime}(t)~=~0.$$
3. Differentiate again
   $$ 2\delta^{\prime}(t)+t\delta^{\prime\prime}(t)~=~0.$$